# Handling null values in OracleCommand parameters

Tags: c#, odp.net

I'm trying to determine how to specify null as a parameter value in an OracleCommand using the following C# code.  I've excerpted the relevant bits, but basically the point is if sal_id comes in with the value 0 it should be stored as null.  I've tried Null, "Null", and a couple other things but so far no luck.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tcustomer(cust_id, salutation_id) VALUES(ORADBA.SEQCUST.NEXTVAL, :salid) RETURNING cust_id INTO :newcid" ;

if (sal_id==0) {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("salid", Null) ;
} else {
  cmd.Parameters.Add("salid", sal_id) ;
}

cmd.Parameters.Add("newcid", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue ;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ;

String newcidval = cmd.Parameters["newcid"].Value.ToString() ;
cmd.Dispose() ;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [`System.DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) insead of `null`.

> The DBNull class represents a
>   nonexistent value. In a database, for
>   example, a column in a row of a table
>   might not contain any data whatsoever.
>   That is, the column is considered to
>   not exist at all instead of merely not
>   having a value. A DBNull object
>   represents the nonexistent column

Comment: The answer from Andrew Hare is bogus like Dan U. posted. It's System.DBNull.Value

Comment: Didn't work for me, not at all in fact... here is how I check it : `Command.Parameters["x"].Value.Equals(OracleDecimal.Null)`

Answer (score 8):

DBNull can not be assigned to any other data type so have to implicit convert it to object.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":number_column", OracleType.Number)).Value = (s.Class.HasValue) ? s.Class.Value : (object)DBNull.Value;
```

where s.Class is int? and parameter value is set as `(object)DBNull.Value` in case it is null

Answer (score 2):

`DBNull.Value` works for some but I needed to cast it to a Oracle Type that implemented `INullable`. I recommend this approach if you are using a Nullable data type:

```
    (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleDecimal)command.Parameters["pKey"].Value)).IsNull
```

Answer (score 2):

you can check Status of your OracleParameter object - if it equals to OracleParameterStatus.NullFetched, nothing was fetched, otherwise use param's Value attribute.

Example:

```
var _myParam = new OracleParameter( "p_param", OracleDbType.Object, ParameterDirection.Output ) { UdtTypeName = "my_schema.MY_TYPE" };

... (add command parameter)
... (execute command)

var _myResponse = _myParam.Status == OracleParameterStatus.NullFetched ? null : MapMyTypeFromOracleType( (MyType)_myParam.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an empty parameter (it will be null to start), and only set the value if `sal_id != 0`:

```
var p = cmd.Parameters.Add("salid", OracleDbType.Int32);
if (sal_id != 0) {
    p.Value = sal_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(((Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleString)comm.Parameters["P_MSG"].Value).IsNull)
{ // is null }
else { // is not null }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

For me `DBNull.Value` didn't work, so I did it like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("salid", "Null") ;
```

and it worked great.